# re.match returns null although the string appears in the sentence

Tags: python, regex, match

I am trying to match a string 'hello world' to a sentence. I think that means it searches the sentence for that string and returns a value that indicates a success.

But when I try this code, all that prints out is 'None'.

```
import re
sentence = "why do we write hello world so often?"
match1 = re.match('hello world', sentence)
print match1
```

Comment: That's not where you should use regex. Use `in`.

Comment: `if 'hello world' in sentence:`. If you need something more complex, you should look into fuzzy search.

Answer (score 2):

`match` looks only at the beginning of the string.

You should use `search` instead:

```
match1 = re.search('hello world', sentence)
```

Note that you shouldn't use regex for this specific task. `hello world` is a very specific text, you can use `in` to check if it's contained in a string. Regexes should be used when you have a *pattern*.

If you insist to use `match`, you should change your regex to:

```
match1 = re.match('.*hello world', sentence)
```

Now `.*` matches everything until the `hello world` token, and the regex "hello world" will match the string "hello world" in your sentence.